# Replace part of a NSString from an NSarray of dictionary with Key A with a string in same NSarray of dictionary with Key B

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, nsstring, nsarray

I have an array of dictionary in the following format.

```
mainArray[0] = { "key1" : "aText", "key2" :"Text to replace A" }
mainArray[1] = { "key1" : "bText", "key2" :"Text to replace B" }
```

and so on.

I have an nsstring which can contain any random text. But if there is an occurrence of "aText" in the string it has to be replaced with the corresponding key2 value as "Text to replace A" and similarly for the rest of the array.

How can this be done just by using [nspredicates](/questions/tagged/nspredicates)/ with out any looping?

NOTE:

My current solution is as follows:

```
NSArray arrayForKey1 = [mainArray valueForKey:@"key1"]; 
NSArray arrayForKey2 = [mainArray valueForKey:@"key2"]; 

for (int i = 0; i < mainArray.count; i ++) { 
   MyString = [MyString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString : [arrayForKey1 objectAtIndex:i]
                                                  withString : [arrayForKey2 objectAtIndex:i]
                                                     options : NSCaseInsensitiveSearch
                                                       range : NSMakeRange(0, MyString.length)
              ]; 
}
```

Comment: What makes you think it can be done with `NSPredicate` or no loop? And how do you envisage `NSPredicate` would help / improve performance?

Comment: If this can be done without the looping then I'm assuming it'll improve the performance a lot, because the string where i'm checking and replacing could be a lengthy one. NSPredicate is one option that I had in my mind. But i'm looking for a better solution than my own with or without NSPredicate.

Comment: You will always need to iterate your list of checks and you will always need to scan the string for matches. Using a predicate just means that you will scan twice if there are any replacements to make...

Comment: Thanks @Wain . I'm just looking for any way my solution can be improved.

Comment: You can ask yourself that why you need mainArray that contains dictionaries? Maybe you can make it to be more simple.

Comment: @ondermerol because that particular mainArray is coming to me as a web service response. The server sends me the data in such format (JSON).

Comment: Then if you don't want to loop, you can implement your json parser, and while creating the json objects from the json string, you can replace any string value with using any condition you want. But if I were you, I will not do that.

Comment: Even I would not play with JSON parser. I just assign my Web response to an NSDictionary whose format is equivalent to JSON. And I'll be needing my mainArray in other places as well. So I cannot modify it also.

Answer (score 0):

The `key1` and `key2` keys are useless if you want to map `aText` to `Text to replace a`.

What you could have is:

```
NSMutableString *input = [@"aText apple bText banana cText carrot" mutableCopy];
NSDictionary *replacements = { @"aText" : @"Text to replace a",
                               @"bText" : @"Text to replace b",
                               @"cText" : @"Text to replace c" };


for (NSString *rep in replacements)
{
    [input replaceOccurrencesOfString:rep withString:[replacements objectForKey:rep]];
}
```

This will work as long as the replacement strings do not contain any of the search strings, otherwise they could be replaced twice.

Comment: Thank you @dreamlax. Your solution might work. But this will be a much costlier one keeping in mind the fact that `MyString` will be lengthy. So iterating through each and every word and checking the dictionary for its replacement is going to run the loop more times than my current solution.

Comment: How is that `for (NSString *rep in input)` working?  Isn't that iterating characters?

Comment: @trojanfoe and @dreamlax. - I tried @dreamlax's solution with an obvious doubt and yes, it will not work. Because it is not a valid format to use inside a `for` loop. It will crash your app with `NSInvalidArgumentException` as the compiler will not know how to split the `NSMutableString` into a `NSString` with no delimiters specified.

Comment: @trojanfoe: sorry it was a typo, it was meant to be iterating over the dictionary.